# If $this->Form->input is empty, don't display field

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I am creating a Cookbook through CakePHP2 utilizing MongoDB database structure. I have my Recipes Controller made, I've created the view, I've created other functions (edit, add, etc.) I can now Add recipes correctly, I can also edit them however, when I click the edit link next to my Recipe, everything pulls up properly but I do not want fields to show up if they are empty.

In my database, my standard structure is as follows:

Recipe

Name:
Type:
Preptime:
Cooktime:

Vegetables:
Meats:
Misc:
Spices:

Cutlery:
Appliances:
Misc:

It's essentially just echo $this->Form->input field, where you can type out the value which corresponds with that piece of data in the database.

What I want fixed:

Obviously with different recipes, you aren't going to have "Meats" in a dessert, or you wouldn't have Vegetables in other dishes, etc.

When I Click "Edit Recipe" and my form pops up with all of my fields, I want the empty fields to be hidden.

If I click "Edit Recipe" for the Chocolate Souffle recipe, there are no Meats or Vegetables in it, and I don't want those input fields to display if the database doesn't have that value in it.

Here's the whole edit.ctp code:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Recipe');


echo '<label><center><font size="5">Change The Name of The Recipe</font></center></label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Name');

echo '<label><center><font size="5">Change The Type of Food</font></center></label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Type');

echo '<label><center><font size="5">Change The Prep & Cook Time</font></center></label>';
echo $this->Form->input('preptime', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Time']['preptime']));
echo $this->Form->input('cooktime', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Time']['cooktime']));

echo '<label><center><font size="5">Change The Ingredients Needed</font></center></label>';


echo '<label>Vegetables</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Vegetables.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Vegetables']));
echo $this->Form->input('Vegetables.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Vegetables']));

echo '<label>Meats</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Meats.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Meats']));
echo $this->Form->input('Meats.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Meats']));

echo '<label>Misc</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Misc.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Misc']));
echo $this->Form->input('Misc.', array('value' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Misc']));

echo '<label>Spices</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Spices.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Spices']));
echo $this->Form->input('Spices.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Ingredients']['Spices']));

echo '<label><center><font size="5">Change Tools Needed</font></center></label>';
echo '<label>Cutlery</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Cutlery.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Cutlery']));
echo $this->Form->input('Cutlery.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Cutlery']));

echo '<label>Appliances</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Appliances.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Appliances']));
echo $this->Form->input('Appliances.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Appliances']));

echo '<label>Misc</label>';
echo $this->Form->input('Misc.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Misc']));
echo $this->Form->input('Misc.', array('values' => $this->request->data['Recipe']['Instructions']['Tools Needed']['Misc']));

echo $this->Form->end('Save Recipe');
```

And here is the RecipeController code:

public function edit($id = null)
    {

```
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Recipe'));
    }

    $recipes = $this->Recipe->findById($id);

    if (!$recipes) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Recipe'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) {
        $this->Recipe->id = $id;
        if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your Recipe has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array(
                'action' => 'index'
            ));
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('You did something WRONG!'));
    }
    if (!$this->request->data) {
       $this->request->data = $recipes;
    }
}
```

There are a couple of small things I need to change, it obviously isn't perfect but my main thing right now is using a condition to hide the fields that are empty.

Code is CakePHP2, database is MongoDB.

Thanks!

Comment: avoid using `<center><font size="5"></font></center>` tags as they were [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) in the 80's'ish ;p use CSS instead.

Comment: Thanks man, i'll stylize using CSS